# Necessary and sufficient condition for having a density in $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, characteristic-functions

Let $X$ be a real random variable, $\phi(x)=E[e^{ixX}],x \in \mathbb{R},$ its characteristic function.

Prove that $\phi \in L^2$ if and only if $X$ is absolutely continuous and having a density $f \in L^2.$ In this case $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}(f(x))^2dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\phi(x)|^2dx.$$
Is there an inversion formula for $f?$

The above equality seems to be Plancherel identity, any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: What have you tried? Which directions have you tried?

Comment: Regarding the equality, it may help to notice that if $X,Y$ are i.i.d with density $f$ and ch. function $\phi$, then by inversion theorem $\frac1{2\pi}\int  e^{-itx}|\phi(t)|^2 \,dt=f_{X-Y}(x)=\int f(x+y)f(y)\,dy$.

Comment: If we have to suppose that $\phi \in L^2,$ then $X-Y$ have a density, but we still have to prove that $X$ has a density.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\mu$ is a positive Borel measure on $\mathbb R$ with $\mu(\mathbb R)=1.$ Define the "Fourier transform" of $\mu$ to be

$$\phi(x)=\hat {\mu}(x) = \int e^{ixt}\,d\mu(t).$$

(All integrals are over $\mathbb R .$) We want to show $\phi\in L^2$ iff $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with $d\mu = \psi\,dx$ and $\psi\in L^2.$ Let's concentrate on the $\implies$ part of the proof, since $\impliedby$ is pretty obvious.

Suppose $\phi\in L^2.$ Then by Plancherel, $\phi=\hat{\psi}$ for some $\psi\in L^2.$ Let $g$ be in the Schwartz space $\mathcal S.$ Using standard identities, we have

$$ \int g\phi   = \int g \hat {\mu} = \int \hat{g}\,d\mu.$$

Similarly,

$$ \int g\phi = \int g\hat {\psi} = \int \hat {g}\psi.$$

So we have $\int \hat{g}\,d\mu = \int \hat {g}\psi$ for all $g\in\mathcal S.$ That implies $\int g\,d\mu = \int g\psi$ for all $g\in\mathcal S.$ Since $\mathcal S$ is dense in $C_0,$ the Riesz Representation theorem shows that $d\mu= \psi(x)\,dx,$ which is the desired result.

Comment: $\psi \in L^1$?

Comment: Can you provide a proof for $\impliedby$? It doesn't seem to be obvious

Comment: It's not clear that $\psi$ is a positive Borel function and that $\int_{\mathbb R} \psi(x)\,dx = \int_{\mathbb R} d\mu =1?$

Comment: As for $\impliedby,$ we have

$$\phi(x)= \int e^{ixt}\psi(t)\,dt$$

with $\psi \in L^2.$ So $\phi$ is the Fourier transform of $\psi.$ By Plancherel, $\phi\in L^2.$

Comment: So really, you got nothing from my answer?

Comment: For $\impliedby,,$ if $\psi \in L^2,$ doesn't mean that $\int e^{ixy}\psi(y)dy$ is well defined, right?